# While loop optimized away

Tags: embedded, assembly, attiny, c++, optimization

I have the following code in my microcontroler program:

```
// Wait for ADC conversion to complete
while ( ( ADCSRA && _BS( ADSC ) ) == _BS( ADSC ) ) {}
```

Where ADCSRA is a register that will change its value once an analog conversion is completed and where I want to wait for a bit to be clear. This bit indicates conversion completed.

Looking at the resulting assembly code, the whole loop is replace by a single instruction:

```
in      r24, 0x06       ; ADCSRA
```

The register is read, but its value isn't even tested!?

How do I have to change my C++ code to instruct the compiler to keep rechecking the register, without unnecessary delaying the program?

I use the avr-gcc toolchain.

**EDIT:**
I changed the code as follows (Thnx: lhballoti):

```
while ( ( ADCSRA & _BS( ADSC ) ) == _BS( ADSC ) ) {}
```

Which changed the assembly code to:

```
38:   36 99           sbic    0x06, 6         ; 6
3a:   fe cf           rjmp    .-4             ; 0x38 <__CCP__+0x4>
```

Which apperently solves the problem.

Check [this](http://wirespeed.xs4all.nl/mediawiki/index.php/Simpel_analog_to_PWM_converter_using_ATtiny13) page for the complete program and its disassembled resulting code.

Comment: Don't you mean to use a bitwise AND?

Comment: usually you would declare the registers to be volatile, and then loops where _you_ don't modify things won't be optimized... but that should be done for you in the include files.

Comment: Although I spotted the mistake right away, I'm having trouble understanding why the compiler optimized the loop away in the first case. If `ADCSRA` isn't volatile, isn't the second case also subject to the same optimization?

Comment: You shouldn't edit your question with the answer, rather accept someones answer or write your own answer and accept it.

Comment: @Kellenjb - jippie added it before it was an answer. lhballoti first just gave it as a comment.

Comment: @Kellenjb it wasn't an answer at the time of writing, merely a comment. Also I cannot do any formatting in comments, rendering the comment very poor to read. That's why I chose to update the question.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You should be using a bitwise AND. The expression in the first `while` loop evaluates to zero,  which causes the compiler to remove the loop altogether.